# Big O notation Python function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

**What is the big O of the foo(A) function** (where n equals the length of A)?
As far as i can tell the foo(4) statement is O(1) for each iteration of the recursion. Also i understand that the running time of the foo(A//8) statement will be logarithmic.

**Therefore, will the running time for the program be bigO(log(n)) ?**

This function is used for practicing running times for a test.

```
def foo(A):
    if A <= 6:
        return 7
    return foo(A//8) + foo(4)
```

Comment: Yes, it will...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. `foo(4)` takes constant time, and you'll have to perform the operation about `log n` (base 8) times - which is, of course, `O(log n)`.

If you're more comfortable using a formula, verify with the [Master Theorem](https://www.nayuki.io/page/master-theorem-solver-javascript) (a = 1, b = 8, k = i = 0).

Answer (score 3):

Your program could be written as the following recurrsion:

```
T(n) = T(n/8) + C
```

Applying [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) where **a=1** and **b=8**

We fall into the second case:

```
n^(log(1) base 8) = n^0 = 1
C = ϴ(1). 
==> T(n) = O(n^(log(a) base b) * log(n)) = O(n^(log(1) base 8) * log(n))
         = n^0 * log(n) = 1*log(n) = O(log(n))
```

Answer (score 3):

`A` is not a vector but an integer hence there is no `N` in this problem and the complexity must be stated in terms of `A`.

Let us simulate the execution with `A=1000`:

```
foo(1000) 
    calls foo(125) and foo(4), i.e.
    calls foo(15) and foo(4), and foo(4), i.e.
    calls foo(1) and foo(4), and foo(4), and foo(4).
```

You get the pattern. Thus the total number of indirect calls to `foo` equals the number of times you can divide `A` by `8` until it gets less or equal to `6`, plus the final call.

This is exactly `Floor(Log8(Ceil(A/7)))+1`, which is indeed `O(Log(A))`.

---

Just for fun:

If you write `A` in octal (base 8), the function `foo` computes `7` times the sum of the octal digits but the rightmost, plus `7` or `14` (if the last digit is a `7`).

Comment: I didn't down vote you. But I can think maybe it is because your answer is not clear. (even though it is correct). And perhaps because there are already answers and yours didn't add anything.

Comment: @TonyTannous: I wrote a concrete answer on purpose (i.e. showing the exact steps that are taken in a particular case, then generalizing). I also contributed the exact formula for the number of calls and fixed the conceptual error of the OP. I don't think this deserves a downvote. [But thanks for caring to comment.]

Comment: I don't think it deserves a down-vote either. But I didn't like the first part of changing `A` with `n`... Otherwise I would have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @TonyTannous: this is a fix of a misconception by the OP, there is no N as A is an integer, not a vector. And also a common mistake to believe that a complexity must be in terms of N rather than anything else.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog same and because the answer is correct and detailed.